# How to insert JavaScript with lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

I need to insert a script like this into my HTML. I use lxml to parse into a tree and then add a new script element like so:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location="http://www.example.com/?one&two&three"
  </script>
```

That's the outcome I want, but instead the ampersands are escaped on write.
Is there a way to get what I want using lxml?

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location="http://www.example.com/?one&amp;two&amp;three"
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is related to the serialization

```
>>> from lxml import etree, html
>>> script = etree.Element('script')
>>> script.text = 'window.location="http://www.example.com/?one&two&three"'
>>> etree.tostring(script)
b'<script>window.location="http://www.example.com/one&amp;two&amp;three"</script>'
>>> html.tostring(script)
b'<script>window.location="http://www.example.com/?one&two&three"</script>'
```

my python version 3.5 and lxml==3.7.3

Comment: I never thought of that, thanks. I'm using python2.7 but it works the same. Additionally, this works:   etree.tostring(script, method='html')